# Restart single uWSGI application (when it's in emperor mode)

Tags: uwsgi

I'm running uWSGI in emperor mode to host a bunch of Django sites based on their individual configs. These are supposed to update when it detects a change in the config file and this largely works when I just `touch uwsgi.ini` the relevant file.

But occasionally I'll mess something up in the Django site and the server won't load. Yeah, yeah, I should be testing better but that's not really the point. When this happens, uWSGI seems to mark the site as dead and stops trying to run it (seems to make sense). Even after I fix the underlying issue, no amount of `touch`ing will get that site's uWSGI process up and running. I have to reload the whole uWSGI server (knocking dozens of sites out at once for a few seconds).

Is there a way to force uWSGI to just reload one of its sites?

Answer (score 0):

you should report emperor logs and its configuration.

Normally the Emperor would continue trying vassals respawns forever.